# Is there any way to refer the current template in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

So the normal ngIf looks like this

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else secondTemplate"></div>
```

My `condition` is complicated in the sense that I want to create `secondTemplate` when the condition is fulfilled and else create the current template.

The `condition` is such that, that I cannot use `!condition` and make it work, I have to use the condition without negate.

Also, I cannot switch the templates.

So is there something to refer the current template? Like `this` or `current`, to refer the current template. Something like this

```
<div *ngIf="condition? then secondTemplate else this"></div>
```

Comment: How exactly is the `condition` formulated? As a general rule, avoid doing any complex calculations in the template and move them to the controller.

Comment: @MichaelD It is bit complicated to explain. Is there any way to refer the current template?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly do you mean by "_refer the current template_"? You could always do `<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>`. See here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ng-template`

```
<span *ngIf="condition == true;else elseBlock">IF Template</span>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <span>Else Template</span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `then-else` combo like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition; then template1; else template2>
   <ng-template #template1>
     Your code for condition-1
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #template2>
     Your code for condition-2
   </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```